# Java generics , bound mismatch: The type is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter

Tags: java, generics

I have a class that should return a list of objects that  extend a BaseDto class.

So I wrote this

```
public class Worker<T extends BaseDto> {

   private T t;

     ArrayList<T> getList() {
      ....
     }  
}
```

and this is the object that should be returned in a list

```
public class MyDTO extends  BaseDto implements Serializable {
...
}
```

but when I write :

```
Worker<MyDTO> q = new Worker<MyDTO>();
```

it doesn't compile with the following error:

> Bound mismatch: The type MyDTO is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter  of the type Worker

What's wrong?

Comment: [It works for me](https://ideone.com/YSsra4). Are you sure you are using the correct import for `Worker`?

Comment: Works for me.  Can you produce an MCVE for us?

Comment: are you sure you are using the correct imports for `Worker`, `BaseDto` and `MyDTO` in all places?

Comment: there might be another `Worker` that doesn't accept `BaseDto` subclasses as a bounded param

Comment: You were right. I had made another BaseDto in another package

Comment: You should post this as the answer or change your question to reflect the new information.

Answer (score 0):

```
Worker<MyDTO> q = new Worker<MyDTO>(); // this is fine
```

The code you provided is supposed to work, I tried it here and it compiles normally.

However, this line will not compile in Java:

```
Worker<BaseDto> dto = q; // this is not
```

Because generic types in Java are **invariant**, which means that two types `List<X>` and `List<Y>` are not compatible even if X or Y are subtypes from each other. In languages with support to **covariance**, this line would compile as MyDTO is a subtype of BaseDto.